# Proofreading services for mathematical texts

Tags: education

Are there any reputable proofreading services out there for texts with mathematical content? I may need such a service soon.

My native language is not English and, even if it were, I would want the basic English of the whole work read through, to make sure everything is top notch English-wise.

Understandably, I hesitate to submit my work to a regular proofreader because of all the formulas throughout the work. It's important that the proofreader should be able, at least approximately, to understand the work and be able to "read" the formulas in context of the surrounding English.

All I require is some basic knowledge of multivariate calculus and probability theory. Basically just what every university student goes through. Nothing too advanced.

Are there any services out there that can provide what I need?

Comment: Not really a mathematical question.

Comment: If you wrote the question without anyone's assistance, your English already looks pretty good!

Comment: @KCd Valid point, but I am on the same page with OP, since not being a native English speaker with relatively decent English proficiency, I am never too sure about articles and punctuation.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A quick google search revealed [this site](http://www.copyediting.co.uk/prolinks.htm).

Rather than go with a professional service, I'd suggest hiring a student. You can probably contact the math department office at any major university in an English-speaking country, and I suspect they will pass on the offer to their undergraduate and graduate students. Just be clear about the size of the job and have an idea how much you're willing to pay.

Comment: Wonderful post.Thank you for taking the time to publish this information very helpful! I’m still waiting for some interesting thoughts from your side in your next post thanks.
http://uk-essay.net

Answer (score 1):

I know it's a bit of a late reply, but I'll say anyway that I'm a maths researcher who actually enjoys proofreading papers and helping with matters of exposition. I've done this service a number of times for colleagues who are not native speakers. So, you could just send me an email.

Comment: Are you still in that bussines? I would like to contanct, can you give your mail?

Comment: gregm112358@yahoo.com

Comment: I have already written you